# Python Shapely could not find 'geos_c.dll' in Windows 10

Tags: python, shapely, windows-10, geos

I was trying to install and work on 'Shapely' library of python on Windows 10. Installation was successful but when I tried to import it then it gave error :

> OSError: Could not find lib geos_c.dll or load any of its variants []

Steps Followed :

```
pip3 install shapely
```

(Successfully installed shapely-1.7.0)

Then I imported library in python3 shell :

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
```

And got the error :

> OSError: Could not find lib geos_c.dll or load any of its variants [].

Platform:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.8.1

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144158/python-geos-and-shapely-on-windows-64

Comment: Yes.. but it didn't worked.

Comment: It may not be the solution you want, but these problems are too difficult to come up with depending on your situation. I think it would be better to use miniconda.